# Binding events in jquery (double event on click...)

Tags: jquery, user-interface, binding

I'm creating a tax calculator and have some problems with binding events. There are five fields:

1. A text field. User has to type his city and the script assigns a number to text value. For example, you type "New York", and when you click "Go!", the system assigns 0.1 to it.
2. Slider. When you move a slider, the number in the field changes.
3. Select box with a few numeric values.
4. and 5. Simple text boxes where you have to type numbers

All of these fields are in a form called "taxcalculator". When you submit it, a function called "calculatesum" is triggered. The problem is that I have to use that sum for another calculation using jquery calculation plugin and the function called "recalc". So, let's assume someone filled in the mentioned fields, but wants to change some of the numbers or the text in the first field. I want to recalculate the other calculation on every change. I managed to bind select box change with:

```
$("[id=select_box_1]").bind("change", recalc);
```

and slider change with similar code.

However, there are problems with triggering "recalc" in two cases.

1: When you start a calculation with clicking "Go!" button, only one function is triggered. I want to accomplish that when you click "Go" button, both of the functions get triggered (calculatesum and recalc). However, only "calculatesum" is triggered, and I have to use "mousemove" or click again on that button to use another function.

2: User can change a city typed in the first field. In that case, numeric value changes, but the numeric field is hidden and I don't know which property to use to trigger the "recalc" function. I thought that "change" is the logical choice, considering that value in the field changes, but it didn't work.

Here is part of my code:

```
<form id="taxcalculator" style="height:150px;" action="#" onsubmit="calculatesum(); return false">

<input type="text" size="20" id="city" name="city" />

<div id="slider"></div>
</div>

<div id="income_1" style="width:300px; margin:0 0 15px 0;">
<select id="income_item_1" style="float:left; width:200px;">            
<option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>        
<option value="2.000">2.000</option>
<option value="4.000">4.000</option>
</select>
</div>

<input type="text" size="20" id="income2" name="income2" />
<input type="text" size="20" id="income3" name="income3" />

<input type="hidden" name="citytaxrate" id="citytaxrate">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" id="go-calc" class="ui-button">
</div>
</form>
```

The calculation goes in this order:

1. A city that user has typed in the city field gets a numeric value assigned and that value is pulled in the "citytaxrate" field
2. All of the values (except "citytaxrate") are summed up using "calculatesum" function that is triggered with clicking on "Go!" button
3. The total sum is used for "recalc" function which uses the total sum, citytaxrate value and two other values I manually inserted in the script.

The main problem is how to make both of the functions get triggered on the same click. Even in HTML I can use

```
onsubmit="calculatesum(), recalc(); return false"
```

However, first click (submit) triggers only "calculatesum" function and another click will trigger "recalc" function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want to bind two methods to the same event you can simply put them in one method and call it. I've never bound two methods to the same so can't comment on why the dual binding is failing.

```
$("#select_box_1").change(theCommonMethod);

function theCommonMethod() {
   recalc();
   calculatesum();
}
```

If you put up some code examples on jsfiddle.net, we could help you with the second problem too.

**EDIT**

After your update, I posted a basic fiddle with most of the events you wanted bound. Have a look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/v5mRe/1/

Just use the jQuery selectors to get at the values you want and then do your calculations and update your text field.

Comment: @JohnP Thank you for your answer. I am java beginner and I would like to ask you to clarify this "theCommonMethod" part. Do I have to change that to "onclick", "onsubmit" or it remaing as it is? And do I have to include "select_box_1", since it works - when I select another option, "recalc" function is triggered.

Comment: You're actually a javaSCIPT beginner, java and javascript are different :) What happens here is that your text box with an id of `select_box_1` triggers the method `theCommonMethod` on the `onchange` event. This method in turn calls your other two methods. Keep in mind, when using jquery, you don't bind your events in the html as `onclick=method()`, You use their binding api.

Comment: Didn't know that :) I understand it this way: when I change the value in the select_box_1, both of the functions get triggered. The thing is I already did achieve that behavior, so I tried to adapt it to solve the second problem ("select_box_1" to "go-calc" and "change" to "submit"). However, I didn't manage to get it working.

Comment: I'm not follwing you too well. Could you update your question and post some more code (mostly the html) and just give a bullet point on what the sequence of actions are?

Comment: @JohnP I edited my question, hopefully I explained it better now.

Comment: Added an example, see if that helps

Comment: Thank you, this one is definitely the code I have been looking for (the part "$('#taxcalculator').submit(function() {" ...). It does work, however I have to click twice again. First click triggers "calculatesum" and another triggers "recalc". Since it works in your example on fiddle, there has to be something wrong with my code. I'll try to find where is the mistake.

Comment: make sure to remove all your `onclick` and `onsubmit` code. The html shouldn't have ANY js in it. Do the binding with jquery

Comment: @JohnP I removed every trace of JS in my HTML code. Then I added another function to the click event to test it (pressing "Go!" button should trigger 3 events). It seems that I have to click on it three times in that case (every click triggers another function). I will keep trying, but if it fails "$("#page").bind("mousemove", recalc);" remains as a work around.

Comment: hmmm, you must have something else clearing the bindings. Binding to the mousemove might not be a good idea. Keep trying!

Comment: @JohnP I tried for days, but obviously there is a conflict between scripts. When I change scripts code to show only alerts (like in your example), one click triggers all alerts (3 of them). But it can't run all of the scripts at once. So I decided to use 2 buttons (first one triggers one script and the other one other scripts). It isn't too complicated and it works. Thanks once again for helping out with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

change only get triggers when you change the control ( when you switch from one text box to other text box) . It is not triggered if the content of the text box is changed.

Use keyup or keydown trigger in the city field to fire the recalc function.

Comment: The problem is that someone types the city and the number assigned to that city gets pulled in another div. This another div and the value inside it is used for calculation, not the "city" field itself. So I can't use keyup or down, since users don't see that div (it is hidden) and they can't type anything in it. Therefore I'm looking for something that's recognizing any change of the value in the field.